# Can I use Unix Time for composite primary keys in database?

Tags: database, timezone, unix-timestamp

In my database we use composite primary keys generated by user-ID and current date/time:

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE (
    Id bigint NOT NULL, -- generated from ticks in UTC timezone
    UserId int NOT NULL,
    Created timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (UserId, Id)
)
```

As `Id` we use `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks` from `.NET Framework`.

Now I would like to use millisecond `Unix Time` instead, because it will be easier to use for people who don't know `.NET Framework`

Are there any potential problems by using `Unix Time` as composite primary key? I heard that it does not save leap seconds, but I'm not sure if this may cause any real problems if I use it in database for my IDs.

Please note that I don't use generated IDs to get creation date/time - we always have a separate `Created` field for this. We also never generate more than one record per second, so duplicates are not a problem.

Comment: This sounds like a future bullet in the foot "We also never generate more than one record per second, so duplicates are not a problem."

Comment: @Ray No it's not. Even if this ever happens, we handle exception 23505 from PostgreSQL and try to use another available key. We also want to use millisecond Unix Time, so we have 1000 available entries per second.

Comment: As long as you're handling it an backing off and retrying and you don't get a lot of collisions

Comment: BTW, what kind of DB are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest concern I'd have is that you may have multiple rows created within the same timestamp, creating a conflict between the first row and all subsequent rows.

Unix Time is typically in whole seconds, though even if you increase precision to milliseconds, you could still end up using the same temporarily-cached value for multiple records, depending on the implementation details of how the timestamp was read from the system clock.

Even with `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks`, under certain circumstances, multiple calls in a tight loop *might* return the same value.  Same with `getutcdate` or other SQL-like commands.

If you need an integer unique identifier, better to use an auto-incrementing integer, which is a feature built in to most databases.

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot use auto-increment IDs because we have sharded database (splitted into many separate instances with the same schema)

Comment: One addition/hint: In most database systems this is called a "sequence" not an auto-increment field.

Comment: @SergeyStupnikov: PK could be composite of the auto-increment + shard identifier where the record is created.

Answer (score 2):

As long as they're unique (no more than one per second per other feilds in the composite key) Mysql will allow timestamps for keys them just fine.

However, I'm worried about your claim

> We also never generate more than one record per second, so duplicates are not a problem.

I've heard this so many times.

- "We'll never have parellel request"
- "We'll never get this many requests per second, etc..."

Just warning you, this is tempting fate bigtime and someone will be cursing you later.

Based on your comment, you've added a detection and backoff/retry for conflicts (key denials), keep an eye out if you scale out horizontally because this is where you may still see issue

- If your servers for example have slighlty off timestamps you could overlap get frequent collisions even with millisecond timestamps--milli's are not as granular as you think, especially when you scale out (I had this happen a  with loadbalanced servers when I tried to create our own UUID function based on timestamps and some other crappy heuristics).
- I'd recommend solving it now not to even have it open for chance by using something like increment column in the DB, a UUID, or at least additional random number fields.